# tkinter command called from menu and key bind conflicting

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, key-bindings

I'm a newbie trying to make menu actions that can also be triggered by shortcuts, like the most common "File > New" and "Ctrl+N".
This is the code I'm trying to work with:

```
import tkinter as tk

def do_nothing(self):
    print("Doing nothing.")

root = tk.Tk()
mainMenu = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=mainMenu)
fileMenu = tk.Menu(mainMenu, tearoff=0)
mainMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=do_nothing, accelerator="Ctrl+N")
root.bind_all("<Control-n>", do_nothing)
tk.mainloop()
```

Here's my issue. When running the code above, the "Ctrl+N" shortcut works fine, but using the menu and clicking on "New" returns the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: do_nothing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I tried to change `def do_nothing(self):` to `def do_nothing():`, but the error is reversed now. Using the menu and clicking on "New" works fine, but the "Ctrl+N" shortcut returns the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: do_nothing() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I'd like to know what could be done to allow both of them to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_nothing(*args):
    print("Doing nothing.")
```

The command callback, the bind callback and the trace callback all have different signatures. To satisfy them all you need to define a lot of defaults, or use `*args`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the late response.

Comment: In case it helps someone else, this answer helped me realise how to solve the same issue but for arguments other than `self`. When calling the function e.g. `self.do_nothing('something')`, declare the original function as `do_nothing(self, *args): something = args[0]`. @Novel, please correct me if there's a better method of doing so!